# How to convert XSLT to plain text with encoded data?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, transformer-model

I am trying to convert a XSLT file to plain text. The problem is XSLT file has encoded values e.g, & is  `&amp;` and Transformer factory outputs encoded value. Is there a better other than using XML decoder and then covert to plain text?

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(XSLT_Source));       
transformer.setOutputProperty("media-type", "text/plain");
transformer.transform(new StreamSource(XSLT_Source), new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream(outputTrager)));
```

Comment: If you can edit the XSLT make sure it uses `<xsl:output method="text"/>`. There might also be a way to do that using the Java API but I don't recall the details and they might depend on the XSLT processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit the stylesheet make sure it uses `<xsl:output method="text"/>`. If you want to set that programmatically with the JAXP API then see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/OutputKeys.html#METHOD, you need to set

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys.METHOD, "text");
```

Comment: This is awesome! I was using wrong output property with media-type. It was unable to  distinguish output format for result tree. Using property  MEHTOD explicitly sets the result tree as text and takes care of encoding.